# Loading Require.js plugins

Tags: plugins, requirejs

How do you load a require.js plugin?!

I've read all the docs  - http://requirejs.org/docs/plugins.html - but unless I've missed it, nowhere does it tell you *how* to load a plugin.  I'm trying to load the "text" one.  If I require something like: `template: 'text!template.html'` Chrome just gives `/text!template.html.js 404 (Object Not Found)`, so presumably the text plugin isn't loading.

I've put it in the same dir as require.js, and tried adding it in my `require` header, but it doesn't seem to find it.

What have I missed?!  I'm using the combined jquery-require.js file, if that is relevant. i.e. http://requirejs.org/docs/download.html#samplejquery

Answer (score 1):

I worked this out.  Nothing to do with `require.js`, schoolboy error with the webserver permissions meant the file wasn't being served.  For reference, in the `require.config` just put `text :"PATH_TO_FILE"` and it will find it when you reference `"text!:..."`.